# Undefined resource path when using a number in the client resource access path

Tags: resources, client, ballerina

When having the following sample ballerina client:

```ballerina
public client class SimpleClient {
    resource function get metadata/[string id]() returns string {
        return "";
    }
}
```

and calling it like: `sampleClient->/metadata/123()`

I get the error `undefined resource path in object`. To get this to work I had to explicitly cast it to `string`: `` sampleClient->/metadata/[string `123`] ``

Is there a better solution to handle this scenario? I don't really understand why the type is not inferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is ballerina does not directly allow numeric literals as a resource path segment. Things that are allowed as resource path segments are:

1. Resource path segment name:= An identifier eg: `metadata`
2. Computed resource access path segment:= `[expression]`
3. Resource access rest segment:= `[spread]`

Since `123` is not an identifier, `sampleClient->/metadata/123()` will be invalid syntax and you should get syntax errors. Because of the target resource segment type is `string` we can do the following to fix the issue.

1. Use quoted identifier which allows to write numbers as identifiers := `simpleClient->/metadata/'123;`
2. Use computed resource access path segment to pass `123` as a `string`:= `simpleClient->/metadata/["123"];`. Note: If you do `simpleClient->/metadata/[123];`, `123` will be considered as `int`